Available triggers for CiviRule 'Update membership status'
I'm trying to use the recently added 'Update membership status' action in CiviRules but every trigger related to 'contribution' appears to not be compatible and I get this warning This action is not available with trigger Recurring Contribution is changed.
I'm wondering which triggers are hence compatible / designed for this action.
